# Make a single reference list for multiple documents

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, bibdesk

How can I create a single reference list that contains precisely the items cited in at least one of several distinct documents?  I do not want to include any references that not actually cited, but the citation can come from one of several documents, and the reference list should be, again, a separate document.

Motivation: This seems to be what is requested by the grant proposal guidelines for the NSF.

Additional information: I'm using BibTeX (with BibDesk on Mac OS X).  The references all come from a single `*.bib` file.

Comment: In other words, you want a document to know which bib items have been cited in other external documents?

Comment: @karlkoeller: Essentially, yes.

Answer (score 4):

[Bibtool](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibtool) can do a lot of the work for you.  Take this `.bib` file:

```
% masterfile.bib
@InProceedings{a,
  crossref =     {z},
  author =       {Author, A.},
  year =         {2001},
  title =        {Alpha},
}
@InProceedings{b,
  crossref =     {z},
  author =       {Buthor, B.},
  year =         {2002},
  title =        {Bravo},
}
@Proceedings{z,
  editor =       {Zuthor, Z.},
  year =         {1999},
  title =        {Zulu},
  publisher =    {Publisher},
  address =      {Address},
}

@Book{book,
  author =   {Smith, John},
  title =    {A Book Title},
  publisher =    {Publisher},
  year =     2000,
  address =      {Address}}

@Article{article,
  author =   {Smythe, Jon},
  title =    {An Artitle Title},
  journal =      {Journal of Journals},
  year =     2000,
  volume =   10,
  number =   2,
  pages =    {100--125}}

@Book{notcited,
  author =   {Schmit, Jean},
  title =    {An Uncited Book},
  publisher =    {Publisher},
  year =     2001,
  address =      {Address}}
```

Now imagine two different input files:

```
% file1.tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}

\cite{a,b,book}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{masterfile}
\end{document}
```

and

```
% file2.tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}

\cite{article,book}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{masterfile}
\end{document}
```

We want to construct a new `.bib` (say: `newbibfile.bib`) that contains the following bib entries: `a`, `b`, `z`, `article`, and `book` (but not `notcited`).  Run `latex` (or `lua|pdf|xelatex`) on your two `.tex` files.  This produces the all-important `.aux` file that `bibtool` can read.  The `bibtool` command is:

```
bibtool -x file1.aux -o newbibfile.bib && bibtool -x file2.aux >> newbibfile.bib
```

This command extracts from `file1` and creates the new `.bib` file, then the second call uses `>>` to append its output to the already-created `newbibfile.bib`.  (If you have more than two files you need to extract from, modify the above command accordingly.)

... Now, many will note that both files cited the entry `book`, which means there will be two `book` entries in `newbibfile.bib`; this is no good.  Good BibTeX-aware editors can help you find and deal with them [Emacs plug!], but `bibtool` can also detect entry key duplicates:

```
bibtool -d newbibfile.bib
```

If you want to combine all this into a one-liner, you could do:

```
bibtool -x file1.aux -o temp.bib && bibtool -x file2.aux >> temp.bib && bibtool -d temp.bib -o newbibfile.bib
```

In our use case, `bibtool` helpfully warns:

```
*** BibTool WARNING: Possible double entries discovered: 
***     book =?= book
***     book
```

and the second `book` entry in `newbibfile.bib` is marked by `###`.  Just find your duplicate entries and delete them.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness sake, a solution with BibDesk:

1. Generate all the files given in the answer by @jon
2. Open `masterfile.bib` in BibDesk
3. Create a new bibliography and save it as `newbibfile.bib`
4. Go to `masterfile.bib` and select `Database —> Select Publications From .aux File` in the menu
5. Choose `file1.aux`
6. Drag the resulting selection of entries into the window containing `newbibfile.bib`
7. Repeat steps 3 through 6 with `file2.aux`
8. Select duplicates (`Database —> Select Duplicates`) and delete them, in order to clean up `newbibfile.bib`.

Eventually you can print the reference list as a separate document, like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{newbibfile}
\end{document}
```